# Append incremental number to specific string in a column

Tags: r, paste, gsub

Im sure this this something basic but I just cannot find a solution that fits. 
I have a large df which looks like:

```
Sample  cat
data1   124
data2   125
data3   126
Test1   Nice
Test2   Fluffy
Sample  Dog
data1   123
data2   124
data3   125
Test1   Good
Test2   Soft
```

I want to add incremental numbers to `Sample`values in the first column so I would get the following output:

```
Sample_1    cat
data1   124
data2   125
data3   126
Test1   Nice
Test2   Fluffy
Sample_2    Dog
data1   123
data2   124
data3   125
Test1   Good
Test2   Soft
```

Ive tried various gsub, grep, paste, paste0 combinations and no joy.

**Example**

```
structure(list(V1 = c("Sample", "data1", "data2", "data3", "Test1", "Test2", "Sample", "data1", "data2", "data3", "Test1", "Test2"), V2 = structure(c(5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 10L), .Label = c("123", "124", "125", "126", "cat", "Dog", "Fluffy", "Good", "Nice", "Soft"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` to get the number of `Samples` and `paste` them, i.e.

```
d1$V1[d1$V1 == 'Sample'] <- paste0(d1$V1[d1$V1 == 'Sample'], '_', unique(cumsum(d1$V1 == 'Sample')))
```

Comment: Maybe using `seq(sum(d1$V1 == 'Sample'))` instead of `unique(cumsum(d1$V1 == 'Sample'))` can be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(V1, "Sample")) %>% 
  mutate(V1 = ifelse(str_detect(V1, "Sample"), paste0("Sample_", row_number()), V1))

df <- df[-which(df$V1 == "Sample"),]


rbind(df2, df)
```

-Brennan